# Shorter way to write this code?

Tags: iphone, refactoring, sdk, uiimageview

I know how to make all these uiimageviews disappear and come back again, but I don't know how to write this shorter.  They are all assigned unique tags 1-35.  I want to check if ALL of them are hidden and then perform an action.

```
if(test.hidden==YES 
       && test2.hidden==YES
       && test3.hidden==YES 
       && test4.hidden==YES 
       && test5.hidden==YES 
       && test6.hidden==YES 
       && test7.hidden==YES 
       && test8.hidden==YES 
       && test9.hidden==YES 
       && test10.hidden==YES 
       && test11.hidden==YES 
       && test12.hidden==YES 
       && test13.hidden==YES 
       && test14.hidden==YES 
       && test15.hidden==YES 
       && test16.hidden==YES 
       && test17.hidden==YES 
       && test18.hidden==YES 
       && test19.hidden==YES 
       && test20.hidden==YES 
       && test21.hidden==YES 
       && test22.hidden==YES 
       && test23.hidden==YES 
       && test24.hidden==YES 
       && test25.hidden==YES 
       && test26.hidden==YES 
       && test27.hidden==YES 
       && test28.hidden==YES 
       && test29.hidden==YES 
       && test30.hidden==YES 
       && test31.hidden==YES 
       && test32.hidden==YES 
       && test33.hidden==YES 
       && test34.hidden==YES 
       && test35.hidden==YES){
do something
}
```

Comment: Don't compare `== YES`. `if(condition)` is enough. `if(condition == YES)` may fail because anything nonzero is a true-value, but may not be equal to 1 (`YES`).

Comment: That seems a little overly paranoid to me. If the method is defined to return a BOOL and returns something other than a BOOL, that's some pretty major fail right there. I'm hoping that Cocoa doesn't actually DO that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you meant tag as in the `-tag` method on UIView, and these views are all in `containerView`

```
BOOL allHidden = YES;
for (int i = 1; allHidden == YES && i <= 35; i++) {
    allHidden = [[containerView viewWithTag:i] isHidden];
}
if (allHidden) {
   do_something();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

How about keeping an array of tests instead?

Then you can simply do something like:

```
int testresult = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 35; i++){
   if(test[i].hidden != YES){
       testresult = 1;
       break;
   }
}

if(testresult == 0){
   // all tests = yes
}
```

Note this uses C arrays rather than an NSArray.  Principally you should switch from having a large collection of similarly named variables to an array of these things -- in ObjC it's advisable (as per the comments on this answer) to use an NSArray.

Comment: Why would he use a C array when he's programing in ObjC?

Comment: @Colin, are C arrays not allowed in ObjC?

Comment: They are allowed, but NSArrays take care of the cleaning up of the objects they hold when they are released.

Comment: Fair enough, my suggestion is primarily to change the storage format, I'm not advocating for C arrays and the solution here is one of concept rather than something ObjC specific.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/BasicPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002170-BAJEAIEE

This may not be exact but something like:

```
BOOL retVal = test.hidden ;
for (int i = 2; i < 36 && retVal; ++i ) {
  id x = [self valueForKey:[NSString stringFromFormat:@"test%d", i]];
  retVal = retVal && x.hidden ;
}
if ( retVal ) {
  // do something
}
```

Though I think storing the test objects in an NSArray would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Are they all contained in the same superview?  If so, try this to take advantage of the fact that they're already in an array:

```
@implementation UIView (testForHiddenSubviews)

- (BOOL) hasHiddenSubviews
  {
  for (UIView *view in self.subviews)
   if (view.hidden) 
    return YES;
  return NO;
  }

- (BOOL) allSubviewsHidden
  {
  for (UIView *view in self.subviews)
    if (!view.hidden) 
      return NO;
  return YES;
  }

@end
```